# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. while Accessing Excel Sheet Cell Values

Tags: c#, linq, excel, openxml

I have a requirement to read values from each row in Excel Sheet and do some calculations with the contained values in order. I seem to have run into some issue accessing the values and would appreciate some help debugging the code below.

```
      public void ProcessRows(IEnumerable<Row> dataRows, SharedStringTable sharedString)
    {
        try
        {
            //Extract the information for each row 
            foreach (Row row in dataRows)
            {
                var cellValues = from cell in row.Descendants<Cell>()
                                 select ((cell.CellValue != null && cell.DataType!=null && cell.DataType.HasValue  )
                                 && (sharedString.HasChildren  && int.Parse(cell.CellValue.InnerText) < sharedString.ChildElements.Count)
                                           ? sharedString.ChildElements[int.Parse(cell.CellValue.InnerText)].InnerText
                                           : ((cell.CellValue.InnerText != null)?cell.CellValue.InnerText:cell.CellValue.Text));


                //Check to verify the row contained data.
                if (cellValues != null && cellValues.Count() > 0)
                {
                    //Create a productdetail object and add it to the list.
                    var values = cellValues.ToArray();
                    ProductItemDetail itemdetail = new ProductItemDetail();
                    itemdetail.RecordID = SessionRecordID;
                    if (values[0] != null)
                        itemdetail.Source = values[0].Trim();
                    if (values[1] != null)
                        itemdetail.Sourcename = values[1].Trim();
                    if (values[2] != null)
                        itemdetail.URLHomePage = values[2].Trim();


                }
            {

    Catch(Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
             }
```

}

The problem seems to happen when I run this line in the code

if (cellValues != null & cellValues.Count() > 0)
                    {
 . . . . .
}

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You might want to wrap "if (cellValues != null & cellValues.Count() > 0) { . . . . . }" in a try...catch statement. That way you will be able to trap the error and decide how to proceed.

Comment: It is all wrapped in a try catch. I am trying to figure out the reason for the exception. I have put into that as many checks as I can to help avert that problem but it persists and I need a better way of getting at the content of the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your LINQ's select you have a condition `cell.CellValue != null` which if false results in an inline if of `((cell.CellValue.InnerText != null)?cell.CellValue.InnerText:cell.CellValue.Text)`  but if `cell.CellValue != null` is false then `cell.CellValue.InnerText != null` will result in your error.

Please try:

```
public void ProcessRows(IEnumerable<Row> dataRows, SharedStringTable sharedString)
{
    try
    {
        //Extract the information for each row 
        foreach (Row row in dataRows)
        {
            var cellValues = from cell in row.Descendants<Cell>()
                select ((cell.CellValue != null && cell.DataType!=null && cell.DataType.HasValue  )
                    && (sharedString.HasChildren  && int.Parse(cell.CellValue.InnerText) < sharedString.ChildElements.Count)
                    ? sharedString.ChildElements[int.Parse(cell.CellValue.InnerText)].InnerText
                    : ((cell.CellValue != null && cell.CellValue.InnerText != null)?cell.CellValue.InnerText:cell.CellValue.Text));


            //Check to verify the row contained data.
            if (cellValues != null && cellValues.Count() > 0)
            {
                //Create a productdetail object and add it to the list.
                var values = cellValues.ToArray();
                ProductItemDetail itemdetail = new ProductItemDetail();
                itemdetail.RecordID = SessionRecordID;
                if (values[0] != null) { itemdetail.Source = values[0].Trim(); }
                if (values[1] != null) { itemdetail.Sourcename = values[1].Trim(); }
                if (values[2] != null) { itemdetail.URLHomePage = values[2].Trim(); }
            }
        }
    }
    Catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```